# Helm cli command to update Image tag

Tags: kubernetes-helm, helm3, harbor

I am trying to login remotely into my Helm repository and update Image tag in the `values.yml` file and later on push my changes into repository.
Can someone please help me in updating Image tag and push helm charts to repo?

```sh
curl -fsSL -o get_helm.sh https://raw.githubusercontent.com/helm/helm/master/scripts/get-helm-3
chmod 700 get_helm.sh
./get_helm.sh
helm repo add charts https://harbor.xxx.com/chartrepo/nodeapp-helm-charts --username ${{ secrets.HARBOR_USERNAME }} --password ${{ secrets.HARBOR_PASSWORD }}
helm repo update
helm  repo list
```

Comment: Do you have an existing setup to push the chart to the repository?  What have you tried so far to update the tag in the chart?

Comment: For first time it will be manual upload of charts then it would be automatic update of charts with new Image tag with every docker image build...I am trying to take pull and then push it to repo but somehow not able to succeed.